# Move Vagrant dir somewhere else

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, vagrant

I have installed Vagrant on my Mac OsX Mountain Lion using `.dmg` package. By default files went to my `/Applications` directory.

So now I have `/Applications/Vagrant` with `bin` and `embeded` dirs inside. This doesn't make much sense as none of those need to be accessible from MacOS Applications menu.

My questions is if there's a better location for those dirs? Thanks.

Comment: Is this causing any problems?

Comment: No. Just want to keep things clean.

Comment: Have you asked the developers why the installation directories they chose were so poorly chosen, for the environment it is being installed in?  Sometimes developers don't understand how poor a design decision something is until a user points it out to them.  It happened to me before.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to keep things clean, it's not the installation directory of Vagrant itself which is important, but rather the directory of your project.
http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/project_setup.html

I would maybe suggest to create a VM folder directly in your Users/NameOfYourUser directory, rather than in your root directory or an /opt or /usr or /var directory, because it will makes the rights and the ownership much easier to manage.

Installing Vagrant in your Applications folder makes it available system wise (>> PATH) which is what you need, so I would suggest you to keep it there.

Comment: I have absolutely no problem moving files to global dirs. I assume that `/Applications/Vagrant/bin/vagrant` can be moved to let's say `/usr/local/bin`. However I'm not sure about `/Applications/Vagrant/embedded` dir and its contents. Where is the good place to put it so vagrant will still work.